# Access Denied in CreateFile2 (Windows 10)

Tags: visual-c++

i am trying to write into a file via my c++ code. But i am getting "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED". Could any one please help me to identify that what i am missing in the below code. I have to write file using c++ as its my project requirement.

```
 HANDLE hFile;    
 hFile = CreateFile2(TEXT("E:\\MyTextFile.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, CREATE_NEW, NULL);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {
        String^ msg = "Uncached Error";

        switch (GetLastError())
        {
            case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: msg = "File Not Found "; break;
            case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED: msg = "Access Denied "; break;
           default: break;
        }

        MessageDialog(msg, "Error").ShowAsync();
    }
    else
    {

        Platform::String^ data = txtReadWrite->Text->ToString();

        WriteFile(hFile,&data, (DWORD)sizeof(data), (DWORD)0, NULL);

        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store apps run in a low-privilege sandbox called an App Container.  They cannot access arbitrary files on the system.

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to the post in this link [Discussion on microsoft forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/981ea410-35cd-4446-904d-d654a2b20e99/access-denied-in-createfile2?forum=vcgeneral)